# JS redirection not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a very basic code where I have two HTML pages, `index.html` being a basic authentication page and `crap.html` being the page where I do, well, some crap.
Now, I have a form on `index.html` which has the `onsubmit()` handler attached to it so that I may check the username and password. If correct, it shows a message and proceeds to redirect the user to `crap.html`.
Now, the issue is that this redirection seems to work fine for wrong credentials but when given the correct credentials, it automatically reloads the `index.html` page, even when there is no code for redirection in `auth.js`.

Here are the codes:

---

**`auth.js`**

```
function passCheck(){
var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
var error = document.getElementById("error");
var set_user = "admin";
var set_pass = "admin";

if(user==set_user && pass==set_pass){
    error.style.color="green";
    error.innerHTML = "AUTHENTICATED CORRECTLY. REDIRECTING NOW.";
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href="../crap.html";
    }, 3000);
}else{
    error.style.color="red";
    error.innerHTML = "WRONG CREDENTIALS. REDIRECTING NOW.";
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href="../index.html";
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

---

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Authentication</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="passCheck()">
        <table border=0>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="password" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="AUTHENTICATE">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
      <center>
            <div id="error"></div>
      </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the full URL instead of .../crap.html? Could potentially narrow down the issue.

Comment: @lolkidoki even if I leave out the redirection part, it still reloads the page automatically.

Comment: Note that this does not add any actual security.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to stop form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's reloading the page is because the form is submitted to the same page. Your form has no action property. To prevent the form from actually submitting, you need to `return false;` from your submit handler.

Alternatively, set the form action in the submit handler. You can do this easily with [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: That worked like a charm.
I returned `false` in both cases, which made all the difference.